# Getting Ruby system to run a 'Make' file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, terminal

I'm having a problem with running a makefile to 'cartoonify' an image. I'm running a RoR application and in my controller I have.

```
def cartoonify
    system('make card FILE=public/cards/gallery/* EXT=.png')
end
```

So, the "gallery" is the location of the 'Makefiles' that it is suppose to run. Here is the code from the Makefile.

```
card:
    @cd /Users/Taylor/cardmaker/rails/public/cards/gallery && ./sketch -k gray -c 185 $(FILE).$(EXT) tmp/tmp_$(FILE).$(EXT)
    @cd /Users/Taylor/cardmaker/rails/public/cards/gallery && ./cartoon -p 70 -e 2 -n 3 tmp/tmp_$(FILE).$(EXT) tmp/grey_$(FILE).$(EXT) 
    @cd /Users/Taylor/cardmaker/rails/public/cards/gallery && ./coloration -h 200 -s 100 -l 0 -r 0 -g 0 -b 100 -B 30 tmp/grey_$(FILE).$(EXT) final/final_$(FILE).$(EXT) 
    @rm /Users/Taylor/cardmaker/rails/public/cards/gallery_$(FILE).$(EXT) tests/tmp/grey_$(FILE).$(EXT)
```

However, when I run the command in terminal it says:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `card'.  Stop.
```

I've never worked with a Makefile before and I was wondering why I can't write "make card FILE= {bla bla name of file} EXT=.png and get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: make sure that version of [tag:make], and current folder as the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make will read and operate on a makefile which is in the current directory, unless you specify a different one with `-f`.  From your comments above it sounds like your current directory is not the right one when you run `make`, so it can't find the makefile

You have to either run `make -f public/cards/gallery/Makefile card FILE=...`, to allow make to find your makefile, or else change working directories first with `make -C public/cards/gallery card FILE=...`

Also I find it unlikely that `FILE=public/cards/gallery/*` is going to work, because the wildcard `*` expands to ALL the files in the directory.